# Chamar função fora do escopo em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, ecmascript-5

Segue o código para explicar meu erro:

```
class Cliente {
showName(name) {
    alert(name)
}

getName(){
  $.get(minha-url)
  .done(function(data) {
    this.showName(data.name)
  })
}
}
```

O método getName retorna um erro pois não encontra `this.ShowName`, naturalemnte pois está fora do escopo.
A pergunta é, como faço para chamar o método `showName` nesta situação?

Comment: Sobre a variável `minha-url`, isso não é um identificador válido para o `JS`, apesar de eu manter isso na minha resposta, creio que você tem um outro nome para a variável como `minhaUrl` ou `minha_url`

Comment: sim, foi só pra ilustrar mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se está usando `class`, está usando `ES6`, então pode usar `Arrow Functions`, que mantém o escopo local de onde foram declaradas, assim o `this` funcionará no seu caso.

```
class Cliente {
  showName(name) {
    alert(name)
  }

  getName() {
    $.get(minha-url).done(data => this.showName(data.name))
  }
}
```

Comment: Cara, funcionou, muito obrigado. Se puder pode me passar um link explicando melhor esse tratamento de escopo da Arrow function. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Podes passar o teu método diretamente como callback e com `.bind`, assim corre no escopo que precisas:

```
class Cliente {
    showName(data) {
        alert(data.name);
    }

    getName() {
        $.get('/url').done(this.showName.bind(this));
    }
}
```

se estiveres a usar um compilador com Babel que aceite propostas do TC39 podes usar [*Public Class Fields*](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/), assim:

```
class Cliente {
    showName = ({name}) => alert(name);
    getName() {
        $.get('/url').done(this.showName);
    }
}
```

Exemplo da segunda opção a funcionar:

```js
class Cliente {
    showName = ({name}) => alert(name);
    getName() {
        $.get('/url').done(this.showName);
    }
}

// estas linhas são só para simular o que `$` faz:
let $ = function() {};
$.prototype.get = function() {return this;};
$.prototype.done = function(fn) {
    fn.call(window, {name: 'teste!'});
};
$ = new $();

new Cliente().getName();
```

Comment: O problema na opção 1 e opção 2 que vc passou é que preciso criar um function que chama meu método pois neste function vou passar o data como parâmetro. A terceira opção achei um pouco complexa pois escreve mais código comparado a solução do Gabriel Katakura. Mas de qualquer forma agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @FelipeCoelho a terceira opção é um exemplo da segunda. E é a que tem menos código de todas as respostas/sugestões. Somente escrevi código para colocar um exemplo a funcionar.

Comment: Tem razão, não havia olhado com detalhe. Obrigado